# Javascript - convert object of object into array and use the key inside array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object of objects which I have converted into an array, I now want to use the key of each item into the array as a separate value.

The code I have tried.

```js
let data = {
  99: {
    "avg": [1,2],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
  100: {
    "avg": [50,10],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
  120: {
    "avg": [42,8],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
}

var arr = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
  return { [key]: data[key] };
});

arr.forEach(element => {
  element.sensor = Object.keys(element);
});

console.log(arr);
```

And the output is

```
[
  {
    "99": {
      "avg": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": []
    },
    "sensor": [
      "99"
    ]
  },
  {
    "100": {
      "avg": [
        50,
        10
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": []
    },
    "sensor": [
      "100"
    ]
  },
  {
    "120": {
      "avg": [
        42,
        8
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": []
    },
    "sensor": [
      "120"
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want the expected output to be like this.

```
     [
  {
    "99": {
      "avg": [
        1,
        2
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": [],
      "sensor": "99"
    }
  },
  {
    "100": {
      "avg": [
        50,
        10
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": [],
      "sensor": "100"
    }
  },
  {
    "120": {
      "avg": [
        42,
        8
      ],
      "min": [],
      "max": [],
      "sensor": "120"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What you are expecting doesn't appear to be valid! A collection of objects inside an object without keys with that single object as the only entry in an array. Are you sure this is what you really want?

Comment: Your expected output object is not a valid object. First object inside array does not have key property. Objects inside that object must be having comma between them. Please make sure that you add correct output object in question so you will get accurate answers.

Comment: Let me edit the question again. Please wait

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `...` spread operator to append the sensor value when converting the object to array itself

```
var arr = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
  return { 
    [key]: { ...data[key], sensor: key } 
  };
});
```

```js
let data = {
  99: {
    "avg": [1,2],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
  100: {
    "avg": [50,10],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
  120: {
    "avg": [42,8],
    "min": [],
    "max": []
  },
}

var arr = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) {
  return { [key]: { ...data[key], sensor: key } };
});

 

console.log(arr);
```